# Is there a Reason why this Iteration Always Lead to a Prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let
$T(n) = n - lpf + 1$

where $n∈\mathbb{N}$,  $n\geq2$ and $lpf =$ least prime factor of $n$.

Let $T^i(n)$ be the output of the $i$th iteration of $T$ on $n$.
**Why is it that for all $n$, there exists some $i$ such that $T^i(n)$ is prime?**

For example, if $n=95$ we have $95 \to 91\to 85\to81\to79$.

Comment: Because $T(n)<n$ and you cannot get $T(n)=1$, otherwise it means that $n$ is prime ( $lpf = n$, i.e. $n$ is prime). So after iterating T you will end up with a prime number.

Comment: **Hint** $T$ is decreasing on $\Bbb N$ so has a *fixed pount* $p$  where $\, T(p) = p \iff {\rm lpf}(p) = 1\iff p\,$ is prime.

Comment: ^^^ typo alert: above should be $\,{\rm lpf}(p) = p,\,$ of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the least prime factor of $n$ is always between $2$ and $n$, so $T(n)$ is between $1$ and $n-1$.  In particular, $T(n)$ is always smaller than $n$, so if we iterate $T$ over and over starting with some integer $n\geq 2$, we'll eventually reach $T^i(n)=1$ for some $i$.  (More formally, you can prove this by strong induction on $n$: either $T(n)=1$, or else $2\leq T(n)<n$ and the induction hypothesis says we'll eventually reach $1$ from $T(n)$.)  But now note that $T(m)=1$ means $m$ is equal to its least prime factor, so $m$ is prime.  Thus $T^i(n)=1$ implies $T^{i-1}(n)$ is prime.