# What's Special about Rowland’s Prime-Generating Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, prime-factorization

Recently I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008897/is-there-a-reason-why-this-iteration-always-lead-to-a-prime) and quickly got back some excellent responses.
I asked the question because I came across a paper by Eric Rowland called "[A Natural Prime-Generating Recurrence](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/JIS/VOL11/Rowland/rowland21.pdf)". The main results on page 4. It appears there was much fanfare in academic news when the paper was released which turns out to be basically the [question I asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008897/is-there-a-reason-why-this-iteration-always-lead-to-a-prime) except, instead of subtracting the lpf, he added it causing his function to climb indefinitely, whereas mine is decreasing.

So basically Rowland's iterations is
$$f(n) = n + lpf – 1$$ starting at 5 (where lpf = least prime factor of $n$) which yields:
$$5→9→11→21→23→45→47→93→95→99→101→201→203→209…$$

The sequence above is exactly the sequence Roweland has in column 2 on page 4 of his article without the duplicates.

**Am I missing why Roweland's sequence is a significant discovery?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [OEIS sequence A190894](https://oeis.org/A190894), which is **not** Rowland's sequence [A106108](https://oeis.org/A106108) but an auxiliary sequence used in proving
the properties of Rowland's sequence. Rowland's sequence is
$$ 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 33, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 69, \ldots $$
which has the recurrence $a(n) = a(n-1) + \gcd(n, a(n-1))$ with $a(1) = 7$,
and the property that the difference between any two terms is either $1$ or a prime.

Comment: But aren’t the differences of Roweland’s sequence which are not 1s simply the lpf of the auxiliary sequence. For example, lpf(5) = 15 – 10, lpf(9)=18 – 15, lpf(11)=33 – 22, lpf(21)=36 – 33, lpf(23)=69 – 46, and so on; consequently we are merely finding lpf's using the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: Just want to ensure that I'm not going insane. Isn't it true that given $n \geq2$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the iteration $f(n) = n + lpf – 1$ will always produce a sequence whose first differences plus 1 is always prime?

Comment: I think you mean  $f(n+1) = f(n) + \text{lpf}(f(n)) - 1$.  Yes, the first difference + 1 of that will be $f(n+1) - f(n) + 1 = \text{lpf}(f(n))$, which by definition of $\text{lpf}$ is always prime as long as $f(n)$ is an integer $\ge 2$.